# Advanced Power Search & Filter of Amazon product data & description beyond Books?

Tags: amazon

Any way to do Advanced Power Search in Amazon product data & description beyond Books?

There is one for Books: http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Search-Books/b?node=241582011

Is there anyway to filter and sort through products with more granular control?

Comment: [Categories seem to be limited](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Search-DVD/b?ie=UTF8&node=241586011)

Comment: @Moab - Any API or outside Amazon way to do so?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it can be done using google (searching specific site) but don't know how, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon have Advanced Search beside Books Department which  I list below:

- [Magazines](https://www.amazon.com/gp/browse.html?node=241588011)
- [Digital Music](https://www.amazon.com/gp/browse.html?node=2258933011)
- [Music](https://www.amazon.com/gp/browse.html?node=241585011)
- [Classical Music](https://www.amazon.com/gp/browse.html?node=362651011)

Amazon list Movies & TV and Toys & Games as Advanced Search but they do not work.

> **Update by OP Alex:**   The site is now available under the new Name & URL: https://www.junglesearch.net/

Full Disclosure: I am the author of [www.jeviz.com](https://www.junglesearch.net/)

[Jeviz.com](https://www.junglesearch.net/) provides more options for Amazon Departments so that a finer grained search can be performed.

There's a self explanatory interactive tour on the site explaining all the features and fields/parameters by which one could search.

First of all you have more sort options in any department. For example Amazon Video provides only 3 sort options but jeviz provides 11 sort options. For more [detailed explanation](https://medium.com/@ceyhunkazel/amazon-search-hack-eliminate-amazon-products-that-have-4-or-5-starts-but-only-few-reviews-f485d35d5969#.mmhdn2krg)

You can do title search in any department and even Book Search has more features in jeviz. You can get more [explanation](https://medium.com/@ceyhunkazel/amazon-book-kindle-search-tips-and-finding-deals-c5cd54dbd760#.o684e1wpc).

[image: Jevis]